# install json for java and set classpath in ubuntu

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile some Java code in Ubuntu 16.04.
when i compile, the following error occurs.please tell me the steps to install json for java and set it as classpath so that i can compile without the -cp.

```
awd@awd-HP-ProBook-450-G3:~/Desktop/thin-mach-java /javajson$ javac -cp /usr/share/java/java-json.jar psp1.java
psp1.java:1: error: package org.json.simple does not exist
import org.json.simple.*;
^
psp1.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject();
^
symbol:   class JSONObject
location: class psp1
psp1.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject();
                           ^
symbol:   class JSONObject
location: class psp1
3 errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that you did not add the library org.json.simple to your project.
If you are using maven, add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise download the package and add it to the project manually. Here you can download it http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm

Comment: but im not using any ide i just compiled my program on terminal.
and i included the .jar file in classpath correct of that im sure.